# How obtain the real mean & se of my exponential fit?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, histogram, exponential

I'm trying to fit at the same time, a gaussian and an exponential on a histogram on the same plot, but when I try to get the mean of the exponential fit, I get something wrong like mean value : `-9.8636992990798974e-07`, (I expect to obtain something like `70`, not `-9.8e-07`).

With the gaussian fit, I have no problem of value.

Here's a print of my plot :

[image: Plot]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in my code for obtaining the mean of my exponential fit:

```
plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(221)

cycle = map(float,cycle)
cycle = np.array(cycle)

list_cycle1 = cycle[cycle < 1000 ]
list_cycle2 = cycle[cycle >= 1000]

plt.hist(list_cycle1, bins=10, normed=True)

xt1 = plt.xticks()[0]
xmin1, xmax1= min(xt1), max(xt1)
lnspc1 = np.linspace(xmin1, xmax1, len(list_cycle1))

m1, s1 = stats.expon.fit(list_cycle1, moments='mv')
pdf_e = stats.expon.pdf(lnspc1, m1, s1)  
plt.plot(lnspc1, pdf_e, label='expon pdf') 

list_mean_1.append(m1)
list_se_1.append(s1)

plt.hist(list_cycle2, bins=10, normed=True)

xt2 = plt.xticks()[0]
xmin2, xmax2= min(xt2), max(xt2)
lnspc2 = np.linspace(xmin2, xmax2, len(list_cycle2))

m2, s2 = stats.norm.fit(list_cycle2)
pdf_g = stats.norm.pdf(lnspc2, m2, s2)
plt.plot(lnspc2, pdf_g, label="Norm")

list_mean_2.append(m2)
list_se_2.append(s2)
```

I could add an example of `list_cycle1` and `list_cycle2` if you want.

PS: I read [this SciPy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html) and I don't understand where I fail in my code to obtain the mean of my exponential fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stats.expon.fit returns the tuple (loc, scale). According to the doc,

scale = 1 / lambda

which is also the mean of the exponential distribution. Therefore, it is the second parameter that you want.

If you want to force the location to be 0, you can pass in the floc parameter to fit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! (i don't know why i was focus on the loc for obtain the mean :S)